# Zoom to specified extent in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am writing a GUI program with matlab for photogrammetry purposes
one part of the program will do interior orientation
I want the program to zoom to an extent that is specified as a rectangle when user enters a number?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.  But you probably need `xlim()` and `ylim()`.

Comment: I mean I would have a line like **zoom([x_min x_max y_min y_max])**that specifies an extent and zooms to that. but I'm sure that line of code does not work in matlab